# Vector space over a field

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a,b,c,d belongs to a field F. F is a set of R.

Now (a,b,c,d) is a 4th order tuple forming a Set V(4) over the field F.

If d=0 for all the sets of V(4).
Then is V a vector space?

My understanding is that V is not a vector space,because even though it satisfies all the axioms of a vector space V,but it always defines vectors in a three dimension rather than the actual 4 dimension space.

Doesn't the axioms of the vector space mean to cover whole of the space rather than mere axioms?
Please explain me ragarding this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does **F is a set of R** means?

Comment: I mean to define field is a set of real numbers.

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The vector space $V(4)$ you're describing we usually denote as $F^4$, the fourfold Cartesian product of F with itself. If we restrict our attention to the subset of vectors in $F^4$ where the last component is $0$, this is indeed a vector subspace of $F^4$ because it satisfies the axioms of being a subspace. Namely, it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. In other words: Yes it's totally possible to have vector spaces inside other vector spaces, this allows linear algebra to be interesting.

Comment: No,it is surely a vector sub space. My question is can it be called a vector space of V(4),because in reality it is a vector space of V(3) and a vector subspace of V(4).